# Насколько почти пустая колонка влияет на объём и скорость таблицы БД?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

У меня есть таблица в БД, которая описывает некую сущность.
Появилась потребность хранить для некоторых экземпларов этой сущности дополнительную информацию. При этом эта дополнительная информация будет присутствовать для очень небольшого числа записей (примерно 5%), для остальных - NULL. И запросы, в которых нужна эта дополнительная информация тоже будет не очень много.

Я рассматриваю два варианта:

1. Добавить дополнительную колонку в имеющуюся таблицу.
2. Создать новую таблицу, в которой будет колонка с айдишниками из первой таблицы, и колонка с нужной дополнительной информацией.

В связи с этим у меня вопрос: насколько целесообразно создавать колонку, в которой большая часть строк гарантированно будет пустой?
Не вызовет ли это ненужного разбухания таблицы? Повлияет ли это на скорость выполнения тех запросов, которые не связаны с информацией в данной колонке? Какие ещё плюсы, минусы, подводные камни в каждом из двух вариантов?

В рамках данной задачи интересует ответ для PosgreSQL и колонки с типом данных UUID. Но более общую информоцию по данному вопросу тоже интересно будет узнать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Именно по postgresql.

NULL не стоит ничего в хранении. Фактически вообще ничего. NULL-значение - это один бит в заголовке строки, где битовая маска NULL'ов присутствует всегда и так.

Производительность чтения данных в строке - NULL влияет только на одну оптимизацию: если в начале строки только данные фиксированной ширины и not null, то до нужного поля можно сместиться байтовым смещением от заголовка. Иначе читать строку целиком. Оптимизация, разумеется, уже не работает для данных переменной длины или если перед ними уже есть значения, возможно содержащие null. Да и это крохи CPU-времени. А база обычно упирается в диски, а не в CPU.

Отдельная таблица - займёт очень на много больше места. Каждая строка в таблице всего о двух полях bigint займёт 40 байт (или даже 44, не уверен на счёт выравнивания), заголовок каждой строки 23 байта занимает. И это без учёта индекса на внешний ключ, от 14 байт на запись (скорее больше, байтовое распределение тут я не знаю). Джойны СУБД тоже умеют делать хорошо и быстро, но вся машинерия как планировщика, обработки MVCC, выполнение самого джойна, дополнительные просмотры индексов - не сравнить с обращением к полю в той же самой строке.

Индекс по полю, чтобы не раздувать, можно сделать частичный по `where fieldname is not null`. Только надо будет проверить, умеет ли планировщик его брать автоматически по условию `where fieldname = ?` или только по `where fieldname = ? and fieldname is not null`. Ну а если нужно условие `is not null` - то всего с 5% заполненных полей он всё равно использоваться не будет.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Есть ли хорошая статья, где можно прочитать подробней про выделение памяти и организацию памяти в postgres?

Comment: К сожалению, ничего целостного в голову не приходит. Стоит почитать internals раздел https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/internals.html И вот сюда закладка у меня есть: http://www.interdb.jp/pg/ Ну и исходники самого pg всегда можно почитать. Там и readme много и комментариев.